# Unable to access H2O Flow using H2O_connection_url

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I am using both H2O and Sparkling Water on Amazon Clusters. I have been using Qubole and have been able to access the Flow UI on that platform. I am currently testing Databricks and Sagemaker, but I am unable to access the Flow UI using either platform (using port 54321). I am using H2O_cluster_version: 3.32.1.3. Do I need to use another port?

Answer (score 2):

Getting the right Flow URL can be tricky because of the changes in the base URL at DBC. There were [some improvements in more recent releases of SW](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/pull/2417) that give the proper URL within Databricks, so make sure you try the latest version.

You should get it from your print/output, when you create an H2OContext. The port would be 9009. If you want to change it, you can use `spark.ext.h2o.client.web.port`.

You can also find the link in "Spark UI" -> "Sparkling Water" tab

The format would be something like: `https://your-dbc-domain/driver-proxy/o/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyy/9009/flow/index.html`

From the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.4/latest-stable/doc/deployment/pysparkling_azure_dbc.html) for reference:

> Flow is accessible via the URL printed out after H2OContext is
> started. Internally we use open port 9009. If you have an environment
> where a different port is open on your Azure Databricks cluster, you
> can configure it via spark.ext.h2o.client.web.port or corresponding
> setter on H2OConf.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the `HTTP ERROR 500 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.ui.UIUtils$.listingTable(Lscala/collection/Seq;Lscala/Function1;Lscala/collection/Iterable;ZLscala/Option;Lscala/collection/Seq;ZZLscala/collection/Seq;)Lscala/collection/Seq;` ?
There's seems to be the breaking change since spark 3.2 and the issues is still open. https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/issues/2870

You could add more details in the issues post with the AWS also.